# function is not returning the answer, only returning the address. What I am here making mistake

Tags: java, linked-list

> 

class LinkedList {

```
static Node head;
static class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}


public Node middleNode(Node head) {
    Node s = head;
    Node f = head;

    while(f != null && f.next != null) {
        s = s.next;
        f = f.next.next;
    }
   return s;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    head = new Node(50);
    head.next = new Node(20);
    head.next.next = new Node(15);
    head.next.next.next = new Node(4);
    head.next.next.next.next = new Node(10);
```

> I think I am here mistaking but I am not guessing what mistake it is

```
    System.out.println("Middle Node: " +list.middleNode(head));

}
```

}

> The output is coming like this, i dont know why. It should come 15 I think.

Middle Node: com.Sachin.LinkedList.IQ$Node@7b23ec81

Answer (score 1):

To have the println() return a meaningful value you need to override Node::toString().

In example

```
class node {
  ...
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return data;
  }
}
```

Unless you override toString, the function will return the standard String, meaning the result you've posted.

If you don't want to ovrride toString(), you can also specify that you want to print data:

```
System.out.println("Middle Node: " +list.middleNode(head).data);
```

Well, that is not really a good idea. Fileds usually are not accessible from outside the class. You should implement a function to read data instead, like

```
class Node{
 ...
 public int getData() {
  return data;
 }
}
```

Then the output line would become:

```
System.out.println("Middle Node: " +list.middleNode(head).getData());
```

Overriding **toString** is usually a good idea when you want to print informations, because Java uses it a lot. Thus you want it to behave like you want.

Having the method **getData()** is also a good idea, reguardless the fact you override toString or not, because you can need it to access the data in functions.

Comment: Thank you, Luca . You have great knowledge. 
I understand your explanation. And you have explained very well in detail. Now my code is working. Thank you , again.